# Will I be able to install Ubuntu Tablet on my Hipstreet Titan tablet?

Tags: installation, flash

I have a Hipstreet Titan Tablet (HS-7dtb4-16G), will I be able to install Ubuntu Tablet on my Hipstreet Titan tablet?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, only two tablets are officially supported and they are Nexus 7 and Nexus 10. However, community members have made Ubuntu run on other devices. Since Ubuntu Touch shares drivers with Android, it should be possible, but it probably won't be easy. And Ubuntu Tablet is nowhere near ready for end-user use. It's not supposed to be.

The short answer to your question is that at this point, you probably won't be able to install Ubuntu on your device. It is theoretically possible, but it would require a lot of work and it will be anything but simple. In the long term, I think there's a good chance someone will enable you to install Ubuntu on it, but only time can tell.